# VPN hangs when reconnecting in Mac OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard

Tags: networking, osx-snow-leopard, vpn

Sometimes my router will loose internet connection or the settings may get reset while I'm logged into my companies VPN. The VPN automatically disconnects. When I try to reconnect, the connection hangs until I get a message saying `The negotiation with the VPN server failed. Verify the server address and try reconnecting.` If I restart my system or wait for about an hour, the VPN works like a charm. Of course, having to restart all of my applications or stop in the middle of a task isn't ideal.

I'm on Mac OSX 10.6.7

I'm using the built in Network Utility with a VPN Interface that was setup by a company administrator.

Not sure where the logs are or how to debug this problem and would appreciate any help! -Mike

Comment: The log is in /var/log/ppp.log, you can view it with the Console utility.  BTW, ignore the /var/log/ppp folder, it's used for the VPN server not the client.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success killing the `pppd` process from Activity Monitor. Use at your own risk, and YMMV--I've seen posts (old ones!) that say this *doesn't* work; also, I'm on 10.8.2.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me when I'm on the VPN and wifi gets disconnected or switches networks.  Solution:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```